# Moving shell code to a function causes it to stop functioning: "no such file or directory"

Tags: bash, shell, parameter-passing

I'm writing one of my first bash scripts that analyses a text document with different regex expressions. The following command does exactly what it's supposed to do:

```
egrep "\\i(\[.*\])?" "$1" | cut -d "{" -f2 | cut -d "}" -f1
```

I decided to move this command to a function, because i need to execute it several times. Problem is: I get a "egrep : no such file or directory"-Error when it's inside a function. Here's the code:

```
function printThis() {
  egrep "\\i(\[.*\])?" "$1" | cut -d "{" -f2 | cut -d "}" -f1
}
...
printThis
```

I'm sure I made a complete beginner's mistake, but I just can't seem to find it. I also alternated my code so it starts with a cat command. in that case i get the same error starting with "cat : ..."

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're calling `printThis()` without an argument, yet it expects one (`$1`) - effectively, you're passing an _empty string_ as a filename to `egrep`, which is what it complains about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're calling `printThis()` without an argument, yet it expects one (`$1`)** - effectively, you're passing an *empty string* as a filename to `egrep`, which is what it complains about.

**Update**: As it turns out, the OP's mistaken assumption was that a function would see the same positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, ...) as the enclosing script scope.
Instead, **parameters must be passed to functions *explicitly***; e.g., to pass the 1st parameter through: `printThis "$1"`; use `"$@"` to pass *all* parameters through.

The remainder of this answer deals with how to check for a mandatory parameter inside a function.

---

- If you want `printThis()` to use *stdin* input instead, simply remove `"$1"`: `grep` will take input from stdin by default (but will ignore stdin input if at least 1 filename operand is given).
- If you do want to pass a *filename* operand: A simple way to *enforce* that one was passed is to use shell parameter expansion with the `${1:?<errMsg>}` construct, which exits the entire shell - not just the function! - with the given error message and an exit code of `1`, if `$1` is missing or empty; e.g.:

```sh
function printThis() {
   : "${1:?$FUNCNAME: ERROR: Please specify a filename.}"
   egrep "\\i(\[.*\])?" "$1" |
     cut -d "{" -f2 | cut -d "}" -f1
}

# ...

# Calling `printThis` without a filename now aborts the script and 
# reports "... printThis: ERROR: Please specify a filename."
printThis
```

Note: While the above method of enforcing the presence of a parameter value with a meaningful error message is convenient, it is tricky for several reasons:

- It terminates the entire shell, not just the function, so a caller from the same shell doesn't get a chance to handle the error.
- Care must be taken not to place the construct in a *subshell*, as then only that subshell is terminated, and execution continues; e.g.,
  `cat -n "${1:?missing file}" | ...` would only terminate the subshell in which `cat` runs, not the current shell (by default, all pipeline segments run in their own subshell). This is the reason why the code above uses `:`, the [null utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#colon), as its own statement to check the parameter.
- The error message printed invariably contains a potentially distracting preamble stating the script's full filename and offending line number, e.g., `/Users/jdoe/scripts/foo: line 7:`

Thus, a better - albeit more verbose - approach is to use an explicit check:

```
function printThis() {
   [[ -n $1 ]] || { echo "$FUNCNAME: Please specify a filename." >&2; return 2; }
   egrep "\\i(\[.*\])?" "$1" |
     cut -d "{" -f2 | cut -d "}" -f1
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! i blindly assumed that functions were able to access the input parameters just like my main script.

Comment: @Pietz: My pleasure. I've updated the answer to address your initial misconception.